# How to fetch out of box metrics tag value and reuse them in micrometer

Tags: prometheus, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I am new to micrometer,so question might be silly.I am using spring actutator with prometheus to register metrics.

I am done with the integration, able to fetch metrics in the console with http://localhost:8080/actuator/prometheus

[image]

Now the requirement is, I want to add 1 dimension(tag in key value pair) to the existing meter which I am able to do with:

this.registry.config.commonTags("userAgent", request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.USER-AGENT));

but the twist is I want to add status value(200/400/500) which is present in the current merics.

so now the metrics should look like:

http_server_requests_count(exception="None",method:"GET",outcome:"SUCCESS",status:"200",uri="/testApi",userAgent":"200-postmanRunTime/7.32",} 4.098

AnyLeads will be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

For Spring Boot 2.x, one way of solving this would be to create a custom sub class of `WebMvcTagsProvider` that extends the `DefaultWebMvcTagsProvider`. The `getTags` method has access to both the request and response and gives the possibility to create a new custom tag. See more in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75579511/how-can-prometheus-start-reporting-on-path-params-as-well/75646240#75646240)

Simple example:

```
public class CustomWebMvcTagsProvider extends DefaultWebMvcTagsProvider {
...

@Override public Iterable<Tag> getTags(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
  Object handler, Throwable exception) {
    var tags = super.getTags(request, response, handler, exception);
    return Tags.of(tags).and("userAgent", 
       format("%s-%s", response.getStatus(), request.getHeader("User-Agent")));
  }
}
```

For Spring Boot 3.x, the `WebMvcTagsProvider` is deprecated. Instead you can use a similar approach and create a custom sub class of `ServerRequestObservationConvention` that extends the `DefaultServerRequestObservationConvention` class. In the `getLowCardinalityKeyValues` you have access to the header and status code.

Simple example:

```
@Service
public class CustomDefaultServerRequestObservationConvention extends
    DefaultServerRequestObservationConvention {

  @Override
  public KeyValues getLowCardinalityKeyValues(ServerRequestObservationContext context) {
    var status = context.getResponse().getStatus();
    var userAgent = context.getCarrier().getHeader("User-Agent");
    var customTag = KeyValue.of("userAgent", format("%s-%s", status, userAgent));

    return KeyValues.of(exception(context), method(context), outcome(context), status(context), uri(context), customTag);
  }
}
```